# Where do I truncate the bits in SHA 256 hash algorithm?

Tags: php, hash, cryptography, sha256

I'm implementing SHA 256 in PHP using strings. Where do you truncate in the algorithm?

There are a lot of places where there's binary addition happening so the no. of bits in the W(i) keep increasing, same with the compression function. So where do I truncate the values?

When I var_dump my array I get this:

```
array(64) { [0]=> string(32) "01100001001000000111010001100101" [1]=> string(32) "01110011011101001000000000000000" [2]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [3]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [4]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [5]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [6]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [7]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [8]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [9]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [10]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [11]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [12]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [13]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [14]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000000000" [15]=> string(32) "00000000000000000000000000110000" [16]=> string(32) "10001111101010001101101001000010" [17]=> string(32) "01110011100100101000000000000000" [18]=> string(32) "01110110010010101111110000010111" [19]=> string(32) "00010000000111001101001100011011" [20]=> string(32) "00100001100101001100011101010011" [21]=> string(32) "11110011111010101110110100111001" [22]=> string(32) "11111011010010111001000111111001" [23]=> string(32) "10111010101100000001011101110101" [24]=> string(33) "100101110100011111001000000101000" [25]=> string(32) "01111111110001011100001000100010" [26]=> string(33) "010000100100001011110010010001101" [27]=> string(32) "01111010110111110100100010111101" [28]=> string(33) "110010001011110100010000011100100" [29]=> string(33) "101001000101000110011011111011111" [30]=> string(33) "111000011011101011011101110010101" [31]=> string(34) "1111001011100001001101111011110110" [32]=> string(34) "1010010011000001000100101100000010" [33]=> string(35) "10101101001100111001111100111111010" [34]=> string(34) "1110100101001100001000011110000110" [35]=> string(36) "100101010100100001101110101111000011" [36]=> string(34) "1110001101001101001101110111011000" [37]=> string(36) "110101001100000100001110011000000101" [38]=> string(36) "100110010110100011010111011101100110" [39]=> string(36) "101110011100110000110001010010110000" [40]=> string(36) "100000101011010110001001000100011101" [41]=> string(37) "1001110001010110110001110110101011101" [42]=> string(37) "1000000101001011010111010000001100100" [43]=> string(37) "1001000011101111000001111110010100100" [44]=> string(38) "10010000101101110001100100010100010101" [45]=> string(37) "1011111001101101011111001000110010000" [46]=> string(39) "100101011110011011000000001001110010001" [47]=> string(37) "1001101011101110111000000100111010000" [48]=> string(39) "010001011100001101101000011010011100010" [49]=> string(38) "10011100010110000011111110010101101000" [50]=> string(39) "110011100111000010101100100101110011001" [51]=> string(38) "11001101111101010001000010110001100100" [52]=> string(40) "1001010000101100000100110100110000100011" [53]=> string(40) "1000010101011111001110000100101100111000" [54]=> string(40) "1111011111011011100000000001110000011101" [55]=> string(40) "0101110001001001110010001011110111010010" [56]=> string(40) "0100111101101110101111101011110000000011" [57]=> string(40) "1100101000101110000000101100000111111110" [58]=> string(40) "1101100110111011011010010001101100000100" [59]=> string(41) "10000100101011000111001100110101010010001" [60]=> string(41) "10111001010111100010000110001111101100110" [61]=> string(42) "110001101011011010100110111110101100101111" [62]=> string(42) "101001011000100100011001011101100100101111" [63]=> string(42) "101110011001100001001100001010110101001111" }
```

Do I truncate the values before pushing them to the array or after the array is done with?
If I truncate before, corresponding iterations will take up truncated values and that changes their values.

Also

```
$tmp=$q4;
$tr1=substr($tmp,-32);

$tmp2=binary_add($s0,$maj);
$tr2=substr($tmp2,-32);

$H=$G;
$G=$F;
$F=$E;
$E=binary_add($tr1,$D);
$D=$C;
$C=$B;
$B=$A;
$A=binary_add($tr1,$tr2);
```

here too notice that I have truncated before adding the temp variables (and updating the var A to H) is this correct?

Comment: Is there any reason you're implementing SHA-256 yourself, instead of using `hash("sha256", $data)`?

Comment: Wow, implementing SHA-256 using strings as bit-arrays?  That's... special.

Comment: yeah basically its my project :P i kinda have to do it .. else my mentor strips me off my stipend :D

Comment: @user3553031 ->when u say special is it good special or bad? i had like one day to make the SHA1 and didnt really have time to study the bit operations in php so i went ahead with strings..

Comment: That would be "bad". The only reason to use hexadecimals or binary string *encoding* for encryption operations is for human viewing. Computers operate on bits, not on strings internally. This is why so much of modern cryptography, especially block ciphers and the related hash functions are specified in binary in the first place. Note that I certainly would not choose PHP to practice crypto. Use for instance C or C# instead. Java is OK as well, but you don't want the complexity of signed bytes if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't be implementing SHA-256 yourself.  You're likely to end up with something that's buggy and slow.  You should use the implementation in your platform's library.  Keep in mind the Rules of Crypto:

1. Never design your own crypto.
2. Never implement your own crypto.
3. Anyone can design crypto that they can't break themselves.

SHA-256 produces a 256-bit output.  It looks like your dump contains the internal state of the algorithm, which is considerably more than 256 bits.  If that's what you have at the end of your SHA-256 function, then you're missing a step.  You shouldn't need to truncate anything to get the final output.

Comment: hey thanks for the input..i understand using standard built-in is what i shud be gunning for but as it so happens this is my project . my mentor has asked me to implement it.. so no options .. coming to the code i am getting the right number of bits as my final hash value but its wrong ..if u have a 32 bit string and u binary add it to another than the no. of bits r likely to increase to 33.. and since the array takes in older values for genrating new ones i am getting the long strings.. any help u can give in this regard wud be amazing .. thanks for ur time